# Selecting Max Value - Adding Criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, max, lookup

@ScottCraner provided the below formula to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36846681/excel-selecting-only-one-max-value/36848708?noredirect=1#comment61318348_36848708), where I wanted Column E of my dataset to read "Max" for the row where the ID contains the max probability for that state. If two IDs for the same State have the same probability, as in Maryland, I wanted "Max" to show for the ID with the nearest Date. If two IDs match on both Probability and Date, then I wanted "Max" to appear for only one ID within each group of States.

```
=IF(ROW(D2)=MIN(IF((ABS($C$2:$C$18-$H$1)=MIN(IF(($A$2:$A$18=A2)*($B$2:$B$18=MAX(IF(($A$2:$A$18=A2),$B$2:$B$18))),ABS($C$2:$C$18-$H$1))))*($A$2:$A$18=A2),ROW($D$2:$D$18))),"Max","")
```

Dataset

```
Column A       Column B     Column C    Column D    Column E
State        Probability       Date        ID       Formula Field
California        10%       12/31/2016    123   
California        20%       1/7/2017      129   
California        23%       1/14/2017     135       Max
Colorado          26%       1/21/2017     141   
Colorado          38%       12/31/2016    147       Max
Illinois          44%       1/14/2017     153       Max
Illinois          44%       1/14/2017     159   
Illinois          20%       1/21/2017     165   
Illinois          35%       1/28/2017     171   
Maryland          41%       2/4/2017      177   
Maryland          41%       12/31/2016    183       Max
Maryland          35%       1/7/2017      189   
Michigan          20%       1/14/2017     195   
Michigan          35%       1/21/2017     201   
Michigan          38%       1/28/2017     207       Max
West Virginia     41%       2/4/2017      213   
West Virginia     44%       2/11/2017     219       Max
```

The formula works just fine. Now I want add criteria such that if Probability = 100% AND the Date is the oldest (i.e. minimum) date then "Max" should be assigned to that record. This criteria is most important and ought to precede all other designations of "Max" as outlined in the formula above. Note that only one "Max" should appear for each group of states (e.g. only one record from California should have "Max" in column E.

Comment: your fomula makes reference to cell H1,  but your data set above does not show what H1 is,  going back to your previous question I am assuming this is a date criteria.  You should clarify that in the question above. To clarify the probability request, is it only 100% that gets the max, value closest to 100% (ie maximum percentage) or is 100% variable and you are wanting to be able to change that at some point something like greater than or equal to 40%.

Comment: The formula @ScottCraner provided seems to work for the criteria you defined. What problem are you seeing?

Comment: @ForwardEd, H1 is =today().

Comment: @OldUgly, you're right. I meant to include the added criteria should be Probability = 100% AND the Date is the oldest (i.e. minimum) date. I will edit the post accordingly.

Comment: @sqlbg - For which data does it not work? Again, what you describe is how it appears to be working.